# Populate HTML select tag from csv file with one column only - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, read.csv

I am attempting to populate a selection tag with just one column from a csv file.

It looks like I can get the 3rd column, but only the first letter appears for each option and a couple extra "." with an undefined at the end.

How to fix this so just the word is populated?

[image]

```js
var csvFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
var select = document.getElementById('select');
csvFile.onload = function() {
  csv_Text = csvFile.responseText;
  csv_TextLines = csv_Text.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < csv_TextLines.length; i++) {
    string = string + "<option>" + csv_TextLines[i][2] + "</option>"
  }

  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = string;
}

csvFile.open("get", "\export.csv", true);
csvFile.send();
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<select name="select" id="select">select...</select>
```

```
id,first_name,color,age,price
1,Richard,Blue,27,126.95
2,Layla,Russian violet,41,23.99
3,Kimberly,Rose ebony,48,172.95
4,Emily,Heliotrope,46,86.99
5,Anna,French lime,49,117.99
6,Julian,Dartmouth green,22,92.99
7,Jeremy,Blue,66,142.95
8,Jeremy,Fuchsia,43,36.95
9,Jennifer,Languid lavender,51,161.95
10,Evelyn,Blue,47,186.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each text line is a string, so `csv_TextLines[i][2]` will return the 3rd character of each line.

What you need is another split with `,` and getting the 3rd element from it.

Pseudo-code:

```js
for (const i = 0; i < csv_TextLines.length; i++) {
  const values = csv_TextLines[i].split(',');

  // checks if values is defined and the 3rd value exists
  if (values?.[2]) {
    string = string + "<option>" + values[2] + "</option>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop if you add `console.log(csv_TextLines[i])` you will see that each item here is a string.  You need to run `.split(',')` on each line to split that line up by the comma characters into an array

```js
var csv_Text = `id,first_name,color,age,price
1,Richard,Blue,27,126.95
2,Layla,Russian violet,41,23.99
3,Kimberly,Rose ebony,48,172.95
4,Emily,Heliotrope,46,86.99
5,Anna,French lime,49,117.99
6,Julian,Dartmouth green,22,92.99
7,Jeremy,Blue,66,142.95
8,Jeremy,Fuchsia,43,36.95
9,Jennifer,Languid lavender,51,161.95
10,Evelyn,Blue,47,186.99`;

var csv_TextLines = csv_Text.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var options = "";
for (var i = 0; i < csv_TextLines.length; i++) {
  var row = csv_TextLines[i];
  var columns = row.split(',');
  options += "<option>" + columns[2] + "</option>"
}

document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<select name="select" id="select">select...</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use the simpler [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- Remove data CSV headers using [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- Construct the HTMLOptions using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- Use `.split(",")` on each row to retrieve the individual cells

```js
fetch("export.csv").then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
  const rows = data.split(/\r?\n/).shift(); // .shift() to remove headers
  const HTMLOptions = rows.map(row => {
    const cells = row.split(",");
    return `<option>${cells[1]}</option>`;
  });
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = HTMLOptions;
});
```